# Mutation para criar um registro com relacionamento

Tags: graphql, prisma

Ambiente:

`Prisma`
`GraphQL`
`GraphQL Yoga`
`NodeJS`
`PostGresql`

Estou tentando fazer uma `mutation` que cadastre uma pessoa e um endereço para essa pessoa.
 Porem Pessoa e Endereço são tabelas separadas, e eu não estou conseguindo fazer o relacionamento entre elas.

Na documentação do `Prisma` é orientado a utilizar o `Create` porem não funciona, e sempre chego no mesmo erro.

Documentação: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/writing-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc6/#nested-object-writes

Erro:

```js
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$_v0_data\" got invalid value { cnpj: \"059.852.698.22\", nome: \"Greice K Tomasi\", user: { connect: [Object] }, create: { endereco: [Object] } }; Field value.endereco of required type EnderecoCreateOneInput! was not provided.\nVariable \"$_v0_data\" got invalid value { cnpj: \"059.852.698.22\", nome: \"Greice K Tomasi\", user: { connect: [Object] }, create: { endereco: [Object] } }; Field \"user\" is not defined by type PessoaCreateInput.\nVariable \"$_v0_data\" got invalid value { cnpj: \"059.852.698.22\", nome: \"Greice K Tomasi\", user: { connect: [Object] }, create: { endereco: [Object] } }; Field \"create\" is not defined by type PessoaCreateInput.",
      "locations": [],
      "path": []
    }
  ]
```

Estou tentando desta forma:

datamodel.prisma

```js
 type Pessoa {
  id: ID ! @unique
  cnpj: String!
  nome: String!
  endereco: Endereco!
}
type Endereco {
  id: ID ! @unique
  rua: String!
  numero: String
  cep: String!
  pessoa: Pessoa!
}
```

schema.graphql

```js
type Mutation {

createPessoa(cnpj: String!, nome: String!, endereco: EnderecoInput!): Pessoa!

}

type Pessoa {
  id: ID !
  cnpj: String!
  nome: String!
  endereco: Endereco!
}

type Endereco {
  id: ID !
  rua: String!
  numero: String
  cep: String!
}

input EnderecoInput {
  rua: String!
  numero: String
  cep: String!
}
```

Mutation.js

```js
async function createPessoa (_, args, ctx, info) {
  const userId = getUserId(ctx)
  return ctx.db.mutation.createPessoa({
    data: {
      cnpj: args.cnpj,
      nome: args.nome,
      user: {
        connect: {  id: userId }
      },
      endereco: {
        rua: args.endereco.rua,
        numero: args.endereco.numero,
        cep: args.endereco.cep
        }
     }
  })
}

module.exports = {
  createPessoa
}
```

Estou tentando criar populando a Mutation desta forma:

```js
mutation {
  createPessoa (
    nome:"Greice K Tomasi", 
    cnpj:"059.852.698.22",
    endereco: {
      rua: "Germano Klann",
      numero: "547",
      cep: "89254220"
    }
  )
  {
    nome
  }
}
```

Coloquei o Projeto no Git, caso alguém preferir olhar por la:

https://github.com/Denis-String/CursoGraphQL

(Para rodar o projeto precisa do Docker)

Passos para start:
 Dentro da pasta do projeto:

- npm install
- docker-compose up

Em outro terminal (com o comando `docker-compose up` rodando)

- prisma deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido o problema:

Na minha `mutation.js` precisava retirar a ligação de `User` com `Pessoa` pois o meu `datamodel.prisma` não estava modelado para fazer essa ligação.

Depois disso, precisava colocar a anotação `create` depois de `endereco` e assim pegar como `args.endereco`.

Segue o trecho do código após as alterações.

```js
async function createPessoa (_, args, ctx, info) {
  const userId = getUserId(ctx)
  return ctx.db.mutation.createPessoa({
    data: {
      cnpj: args.cnpj,
      nome: args.nome,
      endereco: {
        create: {
            rua: args.endereco.rua,
            numero: args.endereco.numero,
            cep: args.endereco.cep
        }
      } 
     }
  })
}

module.exports = {
  createPessoa
}
```

Resolvido com a ajuda de @Plínio Naves